# I want to add Data in JTable when an item is selected from JComboBox in Java?

Tags: java, jtable, jcombobox

I have made a JComboBOx in which I am showing the products that I sell. When a user clicks the Item i search in array list and a Object is returned and from that Object I want to put information in  a two dimensional array and after that I want to add that two dimensional array to the row of the JTable but i am not getting anything in table.
Anyone who can help my how I can add items in JTable when an Item is selected from JComboBox?

```
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String boughtThing = InventoryList.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int NumberOfItems = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Number Item"));

            ImplementInventoryServices service = new ImplementInventoryServices();
            Inventory thing = service.searchInventory(boughtThing);

            double price = thing.getPricePerUnit();
            String nameOfProduct = thing.getInventoryName();
            int stock = thing.getNumberOfInventory();
            int IDofProduct = thing.getInventoryID();

            subtotal = 0;
            subtotal = price * NumberOfItems;

            stock = stock - NumberOfItems;

            data[0][0] = Double.toString(price);
            data[0][1] = nameOfProduct;
            data[0][2] = Integer.toString(NumberOfItems);
            data[0][3] = Double.toString(subtotal);

            info = new Information(price, nameOfProduct, IDofProduct, subtotal);

            Inventory inventory = new Inventory(nameOfProduct, IDofProduct, price, stock);
            ImplementInventoryServices updating = new ImplementInventoryServices();
            updating.updateInventory(nameOfProduct, inventory);
            subTotalList.add(subtotal);
            DataHandlingForInventory.write();

        }
    });


    String [] columns = {"ID","Name","Price Per Unit", "Sub Total"};
    OrignalTable = new JTable(data,columns);
    OrignalTable.setBounds(10, 119, 425, 219);
    InvoiceMake.getContentPane().add(OrignalTable);
```

Comment: OrignalTable = new JTable(data,columns); will *initialize* the table with the values from the array - there's no listener or such for when array values change. You will need to manipulate table model instead

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

Create a `DefaultTableModel` to hold your data and link that to the table:

```
Object [] columns = {"ID","Name","Price Per Unit", "Sub Total"};
tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);
OrignalTable = new JTable(tableModel);
```

Now you can use that model (defined as a field in your class so you have access inside the anonymous ActionListener) to work on the data:

```
      // before
      //  data[0][0] = Double.toString(price);
      //  data[0][1] = nameOfProduct;
      //  data[0][2] = Integer.toString(NumberOfItems);
      //  data[0][3] = Double.toString(subtotal);
      // after
      tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{Double.toString(price),
                             nameOfProduct,
                             Integer.toString(NumberOfItems),
                             Double.toString(subtotal)});
```

Please be sure to read up on the documenentation on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Comment: Thank you very much sir :) That solved my problem and Completed my Assignment too.